# Getting error installing Git on centos server

Tags: linux, centos5, git

I am trying to install git on centos 5.5 and i am getting this error:

```
git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 from webtatic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Net::SMTP::SSL) is needed by package git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-svn-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(URI) >= 1.17 is needed by package subversion-1.6.13-0.1.el5.rf.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package git-svn-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Authen::SASL) is needed by package git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-cvs-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-cvs-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Net::SMTP::SSL) is needed by package git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.7.3-1.w5 is needed by package git-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.7.3-1.w5 is needed by package git-email-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.7.3-1.w5 is needed by package git-all-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I installed using this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
yum install --enablerepo=webtatic git-all
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the control panel solution you're using, since it has exclusions in your yum config that is blocking the Perl modules. Oh, and git is in EPEL.

Comment: i have cpanel/whm VPS. how can i remove that in yum. will that cause any problem in cpanel/whm beacuse it is also based on perl. what is EPEL